# Elastic 1.7.6 ClosedChannelException

Tags: elasticsearch, netty

[DEBUG][http.netty] Caught exception while handling client http traffic, closing connection [id: 0x0c3a8bfd, /ip:35864 :> /ip:9200]
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

Hi guys,

Why do I get this error? Do you have any suggestions? Is there any http connection limit?

Answer (score 0):

That network error occurs when the client network connection disconnects, perhaps because you set a request timeout?

It looks like your Elasticsearch is under severe memory pressure. You've given it less than required GB of heap, and it needs more to cope with your load.